# splash page - put a redirect to home CTA? or rely on the site navigation?

Tags: user-expectation, landing-page, splash-screen

would love to hear people's thoughts on this topic!
currently working on a simple splash page for when a product is "unavailable in your country"

if a user sees this page, do you think its best to:
1) have a CTA which direct them back to the home page?
2) have the user use the site navigation?

i have come across both approaches online - would like to see what practice people think is best. thanks!

Comment: do you have anything "available in your country" on the home page?

Answer (score 1):

**Always have a CTA**

May it be the end of a form, final page of a navigation tree, an internal 404 error page or a unavailability page like yours, it is always suggested to have a direct CTA to help the user get back to the *Homepage* or any central location.

The reason being **context**. When the user encounters a page like this, there is no obvious next step. This makes user lose context  hence causing  confusion as to what needs to be done next.

Comment: though CTA to navigate somewhere should improve the user's perception of the site... e.g. dragging user to the homepage after a submission error or on a misspelled 404 page might not be the best option available :)

Comment: True. Hence the "or to a central location". If it's a form failure, then back to the form page (best case scenario, with entered fields preserved). The idea is to give the user a hook to grab on and get back to a relevant page in the application

Answer (score 0):

It always depends on the scenario. **Usability testing** is the best solution for finding the right decision.

If I am a user I would love to have a CTA button to redirect me from that page.

> As at that moment, I have seen something unexpected and my cognition
>   will not be in 100% active state and I would really love some assistance to
>   redirected me to the most appropriate page so that I can work normally.

Answer (score 0):

What about following call to action:

- Please `<link>register your email</link>` if you wish to be notified about our service availability in `country`.

Where `country` can be populated by the same algorithm that determined the unavailability.

You can also provide an (UNSELECTED by default) option to subscribe to your newsletter on the form, though you shouldn't require a password at this stage yet + you need to provide a way to unsubscribe in the confirmation email.

Answer (score 0):

Look into what can customers do now to get your products. Contact a local representative? Store?

Even more important, avoid having the user ending up in the splash page altogether. The splash page is a representation of user disappointment (products not available) after a sales pitch (browsing the products).

Look into your current architecture and think of ways to avoid the splash screen. Is it a country selector? An option to see shipping estimate in the product detail page? What elements are indicating the user they can purchase the product in their country? How do we make it impossible for those users to never reach the checkout or cart?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the driver is to make the product 'not available in your country' and you know who the user is and the product definitely isn't available, then the product shouldn't be displayed to the user in the first place, nor should the user be able to track down this path.

Nothing more infuriating to be taken to a dead-end page, a poor user experience no matter what you do from here.